# PHP how do I get previous Quarter start and end date

Tags: php, date

I know how to get the previous Quarter number how to turn that into date ranges especially when it goes into the previous year?

```
$Quarter = floor((date('n') - 1) / 3);
```

Comment: if today is 12 october 2018, what date range do you expect?

Comment: Please do not deface your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the [CC BY-SA 3.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4=3.0/)). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
function getQuarter(\DateTime $DateTime) {
    $y = $DateTime->format('Y');
    $m = $DateTime->format('m');
    switch($m) {
        case $m >= 1 && $m <= 3:
            $start = '01/01/'.$y;
            $end = (new DateTime('03/1/'.$y))->modify('Last day of this month')->format('m/d/Y');
            $title = 'Q1 '.$y;
            break;
        case $m >= 4 && $m <= 6:
            $start = '04/01/'.$y;
            $end = (new DateTime('06/1/'.$y))->modify('Last day of this month')->format('m/d/Y');
            $title = 'Q2 '.$y;
            break;
        case $m >= 7 && $m <= 9:
            $start = '07/01/'.$y;
            $end = (new DateTime('09/1/'.$y))->modify('Last day of this month')->format('m/d/Y');
            $title = 'Q3 '.$y;
            break;
        case $m >= 10 && $m <= 12:
            $start = '10/01/'.$y;
            $end = (new DateTime('12/1/'.$y))->modify('Last day of this month')->format('m/d/Y');
            $title = 'Q4 '.$y;
            break;
    }
    return array(
            'start' => $start,
            'end' => $end,
            'title'=>$title,
            'start_nix' => strtotime($start),
            'end_nix' => strtotime($end)
    );
}

print_r(getQuarter(new DateTime()));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [start] => 10/01/2018
    [end] => 12/31/2018
    [title] => Q4 2018
    [start_nix] => 1538377200
    [end_nix] => 1546243200
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/657582bc701cb39bbee1cc4c1d10d0ad38043d1f)

Your in luck I wrote this a wile ago ... This is sort of the brute force way of doing it, but hey it works.  There is probably a "fancier" way, but whatever...

**UPDATE**

Based on some comments using `DateTime` has many advantages, besides just making the code in the function more concise.  For example to get a previous quarter:

```
print_r(getQuarter((new DateTime())->modify('-3 Months'));
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [start] => 07/01/2018
    [end] => 09/30/2018
    [title] => Q3 2018
    [start_nix] => 1530428400
    [end_nix] => 1538290800
)
```

[Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b23596e1b3c66098993d81d0f3a3096092c7f638)

Here the extra parentheses are important (around `new DateTime`)

```
(new DateTime())->modify('-3 Months');
```

This causes the constructor to return the instance of the object, which lets you immediately call modify on it.  It's equivalent to doing this:

```
$DateTime = new DateTime();
$DateTime->modify('-3 Months');
```

But without creating a local variable.

And on the same token you can get the next quarter by doing

```
print_r(getQuarter((new DateTime())->modify('+3 Months'));
```

Another example of this is in the function itself (specifically):

```
(new DateTime('03/1/'.$y))->modify('Last day of this month')
```

What this does is get the last day of whatever month the DateTime object has, in this case it's `3`.  So we don't have to even think of how many days that month has, it just returns the correct number.  These are `Relative Date formats`

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

One last one that may be of use to you is this one `first day of ? this year` where the `?` is the month name. For example:

```
 print_r(getQuarter((new DateTime())->modify('first day of january this year')));
 print_r(getQuarter((new DateTime())->modify('first day of april this year')));
 print_r(getQuarter((new DateTime())->modify('first day of july this year')));
 print_r(getQuarter((new DateTime())->modify('first day of october this year')));
```

Effectively this will give you each quarter this year.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Yea, I made it to create a set of buttons to populate a date range for searches.  For example I have buttons for each quarter and year and month of current year. I slightly modified it so it only returns the current quarter.

Comment: What type of input is it looking for? I have tried feeding it nothing throws error_log messages but seems to return information Argument 1 passed to getQuarter() must be an instance of DateTime, string given, called

Comment: it's in the answer, specifically `getQuarter(new DateTime())` it's a instance of PHP's DateTime class.  http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: For example if you want the quarter Feb is in `getQuarter(new DateTime('2018-1-1'))`, I use date time because it's easier to separate the month and year when dealing with various Date formats.   For example `getQuarter(new DateTime('1/1/2018'))` is the same as above.

Comment: I got it to give me the current Quarter information but I need the previous quarter.

Comment: If I feed it a date 3 months previous say it's 12/31/2018 I change it to mktime(0,0,0,date("m")-3,'10',date("Y"))  and then feed it to function?

Comment: no. You can do it this way `getQuarter((new DateTime())->modify('-3 Months'))`  Notice the `(new DateTime())` the extra set of parentheses is important.

Comment: That is working! Thanks. I need to spend a little more time with this new PHP7 function. I am use to php<7 way of managing dates.

Comment: It's not new, it's been a part of PHP sense `5.2` 2007 ish.  About when I started programing with PHP.  It's just the Object Oriented way to do it. the `(new DateTime)` syntax is newer maybe `5.5` or so (I think).  The relative date formats have been there forever. For example `date('Y-m-d', strtotime('first day of january this year'))`  That was probably valid even in PHP4

Comment: I use it in this function because it's a lot easier to do `$DateTime->format('Y')` then to figure out if the date was `m/d/Y` `Y-m-d` `d-m-y`  or any number of various formats and then try to parse the Year out of it..  It would be possible to do `date('Y', strtotime($date))` and  `date('n', strtotime($date))` instead.  That would be then next easy way.

Comment: this is for current quarter not for previous quarter

Answer (score 3):

A simple one-liner for each start and end date would be:

```
$start = (new DateTime('first day of -' . (((date('n') - 1) % 3) + 3) . ' month'))->format('Y-m-d'); # first day of previous quarter
$end = (new DateTime('last day of -' . (((date('n') - 1) % 3) + 1) . ' month'))->format('Y-m-d'); # last day of previous quarter
```

`DateTime` can work with [relative values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) so you can *describe* which date you want.

Comment: code is for current quarter and the question is for previous quarter !

Comment: @LoveKumar You're wrong, the code had a small bug on specific dates (i.e. 2020-09-01), which has been corrected, but it was intended to calculate previous quarter.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this code. It uses `DateTime` object and its methods.
The main method is `getCurrentQuarterStartDate()`, the other 2 methods use it.
You can obtain not only dates of previous quarter, but of any other quarter in the past and in the future.

```
<?php

echo "Current quarter start: \n";
$dt = getCurrentQuarterStartDate();
var_dump($dt->format('Y-m-d'));

echo "Current quarter end: \n";
$dt = getRelativeQuarterEndDate(0);
var_dump($dt->format('Y-m-d'));

echo "Next quarter start: \n";
$dt = getRelativeQuarterStartDate(1);
var_dump($dt->format('Y-m-d'));

echo "Next quarter end: \n";
$dt = getRelativeQuarterEndDate(1);
var_dump($dt->format('Y-m-d'));


echo "Prev quarter start: \n";
$dt = getRelativeQuarterStartDate(-1);
var_dump($dt->format('Y-m-d'));

echo "Prev quarter end: \n";
$dt = getRelativeQuarterEndDate(-1);
var_dump($dt->format('Y-m-d'));

  function getCurrentQuarterStartDate()
  {
    $dt = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('Europe/Prague'));
    $currentMonth = (int)$dt->format('m');
    $currentYear = (int)$dt->format('Y');
    $currentQuartalNr = ceil($currentMonth / 3); // returns 0.333-4 and it is ceiled to 1-4
    $currentQuartalStartMonth = $currentQuartalNr * 3 - 2; // returns 1,4,7 or 10
    $dt->setDate($currentYear, $currentQuartalStartMonth, 1);
    return $dt;
  }

  /**
   * @param $offset 0 = current quarter, 1 = next, -1 = prev, -2, +5 ...
   */
  function getRelativeQuarterStartDate($offset = 0)
  {
    $currentQStartDate = getCurrentQuarterStartDate();

    if ($offset == 0) {
      return $currentQStartDate;
    }

    if ($offset > 0) {
      $currentQStartDate->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $offset*3 . 'M'));
      return $currentQStartDate;
    }

    if ($offset < 0) {
      $currentQStartDate->sub(new \DateInterval('P' . abs($offset)*3 . 'M'));
      return $currentQStartDate;
    }

  }

  /**
   * @param $offset 0 = current quarter, 1 = next, -1 = prev, -2, +5 ...
   */
  function getRelativeQuarterEndDate($offset = 0)
  {
    $dt = getCurrentQuarterStartDate();

    if ($offset >= 0) {
      $dt->add(new \DateInterval('P' . $offset*3 . 'M'));
    }

    if ($offset < 0) {
      $dt->sub(new \DateInterval('P' . abs($offset)*3 . 'M'));
    }

    $dt->add(new \DateInterval('P3M'));
    $dt->sub(new \DateInterval('P1D'));
    return $dt;
  }
```

Comment: PS: You can test my code in PHP sandbox https://onlinephp.io

Answer (score -1):

**Find Previous Quarter start and end date**

```
function getpreviousQuarterData(\DateTime $DateTime) {
        $y = $DateTime->format('Y');
        $m = $DateTime->format('m');
        switch($m) {
            case $m >= 1 && $m <= 3:
                
                $start = '10/01/'.$y-1;
                $end = (new DateTime('12/1/'.$y-1))->modify('Last day of this month')->format('m/d/'.$y-1);
                $title = 'Q4 '.$y-1;
                break;
            case $m >= 4 && $m <= 6:
              $start = '01/01/'.$y;
                $end = (new DateTime('03/1/'.$y))->modify('Last day of this month')->format('m/d/Y');
                $title = 'Q1 '.$y;
                break;
                
            case $m >= 7 && $m <= 9:
            $start = '04/01/'.$y;
                $end = (new DateTime('06/1/'.$y))->modify('Last day of this month')->format('m/d/Y');
                $title = 'Q2 '.$y;
                break;
                
            case $m >= 10 && $m <= 12:
               $start = '07/01/'.$y;
                $end = (new DateTime('09/1/'.$y))->modify('Last day of this month')->format('m/d/Y');
                $title = 'Q3 '.$y;
                break;
        }
        return array(
                'start' => $start,
                'end' => $end,
                'title'=>$title,
                'start_nix' => strtotime($start),
                'end_nix' => strtotime($end)
        );
    }
```